# Node.js jsdom set document root

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I am trying to load local javascripts with jsdom. 
Now I am wondering how I can make jsdom loading the javascripts from "__dirname/../public".
Can someone help me?

My current code is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures = {
  FetchExternalResources: ["script"],
  ProcessExternalResources: ["script"],
  MutationEvents           : '2.0',
  QuerySelector            : false
};

exports.test = function(req, res) {
    var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/../public/html/lame.html');

    var document = jsdom.jsdom(html, null, {documentRoot: __dirname+'/../public/'});
    var window = document.createWindow();

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      //window.$('script').remove();
      //window.$('[id]').removeAttr('id');
        res.send(window.document.innerHTML);
      window.close();
    });
}
```

The simple HTML page is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title id="title">bum</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/stuff.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello world</h1>
        <h2 id="bam">XXX</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue and got it to work. Try these, in order:

1. `documentRoot` is not documented. The option which *is* [documented](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) is `url`. So replace `documentRoot` with `url`.
2. If the above is not enough, then add a `base` element. I've set my templates like this:

   ```
   <head>
     <base href="@BASE@"></base>
     <!-- ... -->
   </head>
   ```

   where `@BASE@` is replaced with the same value as the one passed to `url`.

The solutions above are extracted from [actual code](https://github.com/mangalam-research/wed/blob/b962c2882be0f0a5b833f6287d8df08ad9f12742/test/lib/wed/jsdomfw.js) in use in a test suite.